# How to send HTTP request in raw JSON format in Postman

Tags: json, flutter, http, postman, http-headers

Below is the HTTP body and header of my JSON. I want to convert it to the expected format of a Postman request where the format is JSON and "raw":

```json
var response = await http.post(
      '${UIData.baseAppUrl}/api/v1/endpoint',
body: {
    "device_id": "$deviceId",
    "country_id": "$countryId",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "phone": "+911111111110"
      },
      {
        "name": "Test 2",
        "email": "test2@test2.com",
        "phone": "+910000000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
  },
```

But when I run this I am getting this error:

> type 'List<Map<String, String>>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: You're seeing that error in Postman? Or are you not running it in Postman, and that information from your question is a red herring?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be in future some one would definitely face this issue for them don't worry

```
var response = await http.post(
      '${UIData.baseAppUrl}/api/v1/endpoint',
body: jsonEncode({
    "device_id": "$deviceId",
    "country_id": "$countryId",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "phone": "+911111111110"
      },
      {
        "name": "Test 2",
        "email": "test2@test2.com",
        "phone": "+910000000000"
      }
    ]
  }),
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
```

I just use wrap body in `jsonEncode()` and use `"Content-Type": "application/json"` in header and magic happen.

Answer (score -1):

Try this hope it's help you

```
body: json.encode(
              {
                "device_id": "$deviceId",
                "country_id": "$countryId",
                "contacts": [
                  {
                    "name": "test",
                    "email": "test@test.com",
                    "phone": "+911111111110"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Test 2",
                    "email": "test2@test2.com",
                    "phone": "+910000000000"
                  }
                ]
              });
```

Comment: so do i need to decode it on backend @Boffin Coders ?